# Illegal access error in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have this error in android studio , please tell me how can i solve this problem?
**IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersion$AndroidVersionException.**
that was my ERROR

Comment: try this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222920&sort=-modified&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Modified

Answer (score 0):

There may be 2 reasons of this problem:
1. SDK Manager fails to load packages and crashes if the package versions are somehow off.
2. It has trouble initializing the AndroidVersionException class.

It would be great if you gave more details